# Unable to deploy Python Flask application in Google App Engine Flex Environment

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, google-cloud-platform

I have searched in multiple places and have tried multiple ways to find a solution to this. But nothing was helpful, can you please help me provide the solution. It is getting extremely difficult to host a python flask application in google app engine flexible environment. Python code: "getresource.py"

**[Here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/quickstart) is the link from google to deploy Python Flask application**

**Here is the simple code:**

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from pymysql import connections, ProgrammingError, DatabaseError, MySQLError, DataError
from os import environ

DB_HOST = environ.get("DB_HOST")
USER = environ.get("USER")
PWD = environ.get("PASSWORD")
DATABASE = environ.get("DATABASE")

app = Flask(__name__)

dbconn = connections.Connection(
                                host=DB_HOST,
                                port=3306,
                                user=USER,
                                password=PWD,
                                db=DATABASE
                                )

@app.route("/getResource/<id>", methods=['GET'])
def getresource(id):
    result = ()
    select_sql = "SELECT `id`, `firstName`, `middleName`, `lastName`, `listOfTechWorkedOn`, `certifications`, `projects`, `applicationWorkLoadTypes` FROM `resource` WHERE `id`=%s"
    cursor = dbconn.cursor()

    try:
        cursor.execute(select_sql, (id))
        result = cursor.fetchone()

        response = {}
        response['id'] = result[0]
        response['firstName'] = result[1]
        response['middleName'] = result[2]
        response['lastName'] = result[3]
        response['listOfTechWorkedOn'] = result[4]
        response['certifications'] = result[5]
        response['projects'] = result[6]
        response['applicationWorkLoadTypes'] = result[7]

        return jsonify(response)

    except ProgrammingError as p:
        return 
    except DatabaseError as d:
        return d
    except MySQLError as m:
        return m
    except DataError as de:
        return de

    dbconn.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1',port=8080, debug=True)
```

**Here is the app.yaml file**

```
runtime: python
env: flex
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT getresource:app
service: getresource

runtime_config:
  python_version: 3

manual_scaling:
  instances: 1

env_variables:
  DB_HOST: "1.2.3.4"
  USER: "root"
  PASSWORD: "abcdefg"
  DATABASE: "abcd"
```

requirements.txt file

```
Flask==1.0.2
gunicorn==19.9.0
PyMySQL==0.9.2
```

I am getting the following error: "gcloud app deploy"

ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] An internal error occurred during deployment.

I have tried multiple ways, like changing the python code, putting google cloud libraries in the requirements.txt, chaning port, service name etc. But nothing seems to be working.

And surprisingly, I am not getting the error trace in stackdriver logs as well. And Google does not have proper answer it seems (at least from all the googling that i have done)

**gcloud version**

```
Google Cloud SDK 222.0.0
bq 2.0.36
core 2018.10.19
gsutil 4.34
```

**

- EDIT:

** Thanks for all the response. I tried all the options, but getting the same error with following debug message. I cannot make anything out of it

Thanks for the response. I tried with all the suggested options, but getting the same error. Following is the debug log, and I cannot make anything out of it.

```
Updating service [getresource] (this may take several minutes)...failed.
DEBUG: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] An internal error occurred during deployment.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\M1044921\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\calliope\cli.py", line 841, in Execute
    resources = calliope_command.Run(cli=self, args=args)
  File "C:\Users\M1044921\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\calliope\backend.py", line 770, in Run
    resources = command_instance.Run(args)
  File "C:\Users\M1044921\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\surface\app\deploy.py", line 90, in Run
    parallel_build=False)
  File "C:\Users\M1044921\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\command_lib\app\deploy_util.py", line 620, in RunDeploy
    flex_image_build_option=flex_image_build_option)
  File "C:\Users\M1044921\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\command_lib\app\deploy_util.py", line 422, in Deploy
    extra_config_settings)
  File "C:\Users\M1044921\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\api_lib\app\appengine_api_client.py", line 207, in DeployService
    poller=done_poller)
  File "C:\Users\M1044921\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\api_lib\app\operations_util.py", line 315, in WaitForOperation
    sleep_ms=retry_interval)
  File "C:\Users\M1044921\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\api_lib\util\waiter.py", line 254, in WaitFor
    sleep_ms, _StatusUpdate)
  File "C:\Users\M1044921\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\api_lib\util\waiter.py", line 316, in PollUntilDone
    sleep_ms=sleep_ms)
  File "C:\Users\M1044921\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\core\util\retry.py", line 229, in RetryOnResult
    if not should_retry(result, state):
  File "C:\Users\M1044921\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\api_lib\util\waiter.py", line 310, in _IsNotDone
    return not poller.IsDone(operation)
  File "C:\Users\M1044921\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\api_lib\app\operations_util.py", line 184, in IsDone
    encoding.MessageToPyValue(operation.error)))
OperationError: Error Response: [13] An internal error occurred during deployment.
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] An internal error occurred during deployment.
```

Comment: I don't see any configuration for [resource setting](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/reference/app-yaml#resource-settings) in your app.yaml file. Could you add resource settings to your app.yaml file and retry to deploy your app?

Comment: You may use [--verbosity flag](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/#--verbosity) set to debug along with the deploy command you are using for the stack trace.

Comment: Another great place to check is your project's Activity Feed on the main console page. It'll show you situations where GAE couldn't deploy because you're over IPs in use or other similar issues.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried with all the suggested options, but getting the same error. Following is the debug log, and I cannot make anything out of it.

Comment: The debug log has been put in the main post itself

Comment: I could reproduce the error in Cloud Shell by using the "USER" environment variable. So, It seems this environment variables cannot be overwritten. So I recommend to change the name of "USER" environment variable and let me know if this resolves the issue.